# Equation-driven smoothly shaded concentric shapes

Tags: java, r, math, parametric-equations

### Background

Looking to create interesting video transitions (in grayscale).

### Problem

Given [equations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20=%2016%20sin%5E3%20t,%20y%20=%20%2813%20cos%20t%20-%205%20cos%202t%20-%202%20cos%203t%20-%20cos%204t%29) that represent a closed, symmetrical shape, plot the outline and concentrically shade the shape towards its centre.

### Example

Consider the following equations:

```
x = 16 * sin(t)^3
y = 13 * cos(t) - 5 * cos(2 * t) - 2 * cos(3 * t) - cos(4 * t)
t = [0:2 * pi]
```

When plotted:

[image]

When shaded, it would resemble (not shown completely shaded, but sufficient to show the idea):

[image]

Notice that shading is darkest on the outside (e.g., #000000 RGB hex), then lightens as it fills to the centre. The centre would be a white (e.g., #FFFFFF) dot.

### Questions

1. What would be the most expedient way to produce high-resolution, concentrically shaded grayscale images, such as the shaded heart above?
2. What are such closed, symmetrical shapes formally called?

Thank you!

### Ideas

- Use a library such as http://code.google.com/p/jmathplot/
- Use GNUPlot
- Use R
- Plot using Wolfram Alpha, use ImageMagick to create smaller concentric versions

Comment: This was the first of two popular questions regarding "how to plot a heart". I suspect the respondents to the second question did not know of this one when they responded (at least I didn't). So if you want other approaches you might also want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082429/plot-a-heart-in-r

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this in R:

```
# create palette
greyScale <- colorRampPalette(c("black","white"))

# function to draw shape
plotHeart <- function(r, col){
  t <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)
  x <- r*sin(t)^3
  y <- (13*r/16)*cos(t) - (5*r/16)*cos(2*t) - (2*r/16)*cos(3*t) - (r/16)*cos(4*t)
  polygon(x,y,col=col,border=NA)
}



# create new plot canvas
plot.new()
# limits are approximate here
plot.window(xlim=c(-16,16),ylim=c(-16,13))

# use mapply to loop
mapply(plotHeart,seq(16,0,length.out=100),greyScale(100))
```

Which results in:

[image: Filled heart plot]

This works by repeated drawing filled polygons of decreasing size and different colour atop of one another. To answer your questions:

(1) This was produced by my machine (a modest Core 2 duo laptop) in 0.09 seconds. They may be other languages/implementations that are faster, but this seems quick enough to me.

(2) A planar shape made up of lines which do not cross other is usually called a simple polygon.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis I've added a bit more to answer your questions more directly. This method is pretty general - you just need to supply a different function to draw the shape and make sure it has a scale parameter (the `r` in my function). The equations you supplied for the heart plot are known as parametric equations.

Answer (score 1):

Using [*2D Graphics*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), this [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.gui/msg/330d094316bc1f55) alters the transparency of concentric circles using `drawOval()` to achieve a similar effect, but the approach can be extended to `draw()` any class implementing the [`Shape`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface. The `createTransformedShape()` method of [`AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) may be used to translate and scale the outline concentrically.